# Remove VS Code File Outliner Options After Tabs (Breadcrumbs)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, settings, visual-studio-code

I would like to setup my vs code in a clean and minimal way, so that I could focus more on coding. Something bother me. I don't know what it is called specifically. I assume this is called a the file outline after the tab area.

**How do I remove this section on my VS Code?** Screenshot attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bar is called *breadcrumbs*.

To disable it, first go to Settings via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> shortcut. Next, search for the `Breadcrumbs: Enabled` option. Untick the checkbox to hide the breadcrumbs bar.

This is what your Settings page looks like after you untick that box:

[image: Breadcrumbs option]

Comment: Yes. That's solved it. Thank you for helping out. ❤️ 